# Passig a data via "this.$router.push" in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am coding a restaurant review project with Django REST and Vue.js. I use google place ID as PK for my restaurants since Google Place ID are unique and I use Google Place Autocomplete in my project.

So basically I have an autocomplete that get a restaurant Place ID whenever the user select it.
Then I want to redirect automatically to another route where I will fetch all the reviews for that restaurant with an API, (`/api/restaurant_review/Google Place ID/`), using that Google Place ID.

This is my navbar component:

```
<template>        
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-row justify-content-end">
        <vue-google-autocomplete
          id="map"
          class="form-control mr-sm-2"
          placeholder="Find a restaurant"
          v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
          country="fr"
          types="establishment"
        ></vue-google-autocomplete>
</template>


<script>
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from "vue-google-autocomplete";
export default {
  name: "NavbarComponent",
  components: { VueGoogleAutocomplete },
  data() {
    return {
      requestUser: null,
      addressData: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.setRequestUser();
  },
  methods: {        
    getAddressData(addressData, placeResultData) {
      this.placeResultData = placeResultData;
      this.addressData = addressData;          
      this.$router.push({ name: "reviews", params: { id : this.placeResultData.place_id }})
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

For now I made a dummy "reviews" view that only shows an "Hello World" message. Redirection is working fine but I can't find a way to check if my "id" is available in my reviews view. And I don't know if it is the right way to do so either. As well, is it possible to pass more than one params?

Comment: In my "reviews" view I will have a template that will display all the reviews with a v-for loop. I will get all the reviews from an API service that will connect to an endpoint with my Google Place Id as parameters. I was just asking if doing like I did, will be the selected restaurant Google Place Id available in the "reviews" view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in the [official guide](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html), you can define props for your route-able components (eg *"review"*) and have Vue Router pass in any route params.

For example, in your route definition

```js
{
  name: "review",
  path: "/review/:id",
  component: Review,
  props: true //  convert path parameters like "id" to props
}
```

Then in your component, something like the following

```js
export default {
  props: { id: String } //  passed in via the :id route parameter
  async created () {
    const response = await apiCall(`/api/restaurant_review/${encodeURIComponent(this.id)}`)
  }
}
```

---

> is it possible to pass more than one params?

Absolutely. You can define as many route parameters as you want, eg

```js
{
  path: "/my-path/:foo/:bar/:baz"
}
```

When using `$router.push()`, you can also pass in extra params that are not part of the path. For example, using your *reviews* route above

```js
this.$router.push({ name: "reviews", params: {
  id: this.placeResultData.place_id,
  title: this.placeResultData.name //  just guessing here
}})
```

You can then access these via

```js
this.$route.params.title
```

or define props but for these I'd recommend making them optional since they won't come from the path and therefore can't come from direct linking

```js
props: {
  fromPath: String, // from path and required
  optionalParam: {
    required: false,
    default: "Some default value
  }
}
```